# Loop worksheets containing certain characters

Tags: excel, vba

I want to loop the below code on all sheets that contain "12MN" in the sheet name. The code is currently built to just run on the one sheet. If there's a cleaner code of what I already have, that'd be great too. TIA.

```
Sub TransferValuesOnly()

Dim rng As Range

'Grab Some Data and Store it in a "Range" variable
    Set rng = Worksheets("John Smith 12MN").Range("B7:R18")

'Transfer Values to same spot in another worksheet (Mimics PasteSpecial Values Only)
    Worksheets("John Smith 12MN").Range("B6").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng.Cells.Value

'Grab Some Data and Store it in a "Range" variable
    Set rng = Worksheets("John Smith 12MN").Range("B24:R35")

'Transfer Values to same spot in another worksheet (Mimics PasteSpecial Values Only)
    Worksheets("John Smith 12MN").Range("B23").Range("B23").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Cells.Value = rng.Cells.Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a Worksheet loop
2. Check name with `InStr`
3. Swap your hardcoded sheet references with the loop sheet reference (`ws`)

---

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If InStr(ws.Name, "12MN") Then

        Set rng = ws.Range("B7:R18")
        ws.Range("B6").Resize(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Value = rng.Value

    End If
Next ws
```

Comment: I only copied one of your ranges for example. Replicate for your second value swap